# Ng-src updates but src does not when deleting photo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Context of the question:**

I'm using the solution from this question: [How to update AngularJS view when the value has not changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155022/how-to-update-angularjs-view-when-the-value-has-not-changed)
So in my view I have:

```
 <img ng-src="{{user.photo.pathRelative}}{{randomStr}}" alt=""/>
```

when I change the photo I run the following code in my contoller:

```
 $scope.user.photo.pathRelative = somePathToPhoto;
 $scope.randomStr  = '?randomStr=' +  new Date().getTime();
```

This results in the following html (and everyting works as it should):

```
<img ng-src="img/profiles/5350f142dd9624b818d90007/5350f142dd9624b818d90007.png?randomStr=1398159116845" alt="" src="img/profiles/5350f142dd9624b818d90007/5350f142dd9624b818d90007.png?randomStr=1398159116845">
```

**Question:**

Now I want to allow user to delete this photo, so when he hits the delete button I do:

```
 $scope.user.photo.pathRelative = '';
 $scope.randomStr  = '';
```

However, this results in the following html:

```
<img ng-src="" alt="" src="?randomStr=1398159116845">
```

So src attribute is still set, hence the browers tries to render it but obviously the path is not valid.

Any hints why this src is set to incorrect value?

Comment: Maybe the delete function runs in a different scope. It's hard to say without any code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to get rid of the `img` element in case the path is not set.

Comment: yes, currently I use ng-show, however, I would like to understand why my current solution does not work.

Comment: Well, here's the spec: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/ngSrcSpec.js .

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (actually this is by design). See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493718/645428) and a workaround.